# ELMAH and API controller in MVC4 not logging errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah

Using an API controller in MVC4, when the controller action throws an exception, ELMAH does not log the error.

I think the problem is that MVC4 sets the HTTP status code to 500, and it returns the exception details in a JSON object, but it does not throw an unhandled exception so ELMAH never sees it.

How can I get ELMAH to capture all responses where the status code is not 200?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that API controllers are in Web API, not MVC. The separate execution paths for each is often the cause of incompatibility of an MVC-targeted library with Web API. Each request either goes MVC, or it goes Web API. The two are side-by-side and don't interact (Web API is not a feature inside MVC execution). They have different contexts, different route tables, different configs, all different, all separate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The anwser described before doesn't work. I've tried on my test server and received an error ("The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces: IAuthorizationFilter, IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter.")

Then I realized what happened ....  you are trying to add the custom filter to the MVC Global Filter (filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());)

To fix that, I've split the filter registration in GlobalFilter and HttpFilter

FilterConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterHttpFilters(HttpFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
    }
```

Global.asax

```
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    FilterConfig.RegisterHttpFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);
```

;-)

Comment: With the current scaffolding of Web API the filter should be registered in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs.

config.Filters.Add(new ElmahExceptionFilter());

Comment: I just installed via nuget Elmah.MVC. super easy to get going, but, not logging 500 errors. I understand the answer above, but, don't see the ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter (shown in the code snippet above) in my Elmah.* or Elmah.Mvc.* spaces EDIT: oops, I see now.. it's a class that you write yourself.. and it's shown in O.P.'s code snippet. Sorry! ;)

Comment: Hi. This works and error gets logged to elmah, but no mail is being sent for all api 500s. What could be the solution to this ?

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE: This answer does not work in latest versions. Use julianox's answer.**

Answer found from information here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling

Where the exception filter logs to elmah:

```
public class ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);

        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(actionExecutedContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

but you also have to add the error filter to the GlobalConfiguration filters:

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
        filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

Comment: Great stuff. I struggled with this and hadn't added the Elmah filter to the GlobalConfiguration.

Comment: When I did this, it didn't work at all unless I added the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter()); in the RegisterGlobalFilters method. Shouldn't the filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter()); line have done it? What's the point of having both?

Comment: @JustinP8 WebApi has almost completely recreated some of the things that were already in MVC.  Although this is frustrating you can see that WebApi and MVC are different characters - one UI orientated the other software orientated.  If you check out the types returned by GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters (HttpFilterCollection) and GlobalFilters.Filters (GlobalFilterCollection) you can see they are different beasts.

Comment: This does not worked for me. I got this error `The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces: IAuthorizationFilter, IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter.` The other answer above (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13264550/1182982) worked for me.