# How to set up Elmah with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, elmah

I've tried many elmah nugets but they didn't work with ASP.NET Web API. Does anybody knows why? Is there any work around for that?

Answer (score 24):

There are two options by using ELMAH to capture exceptions in WEB API.

If you want to capture **errors that are encountered in Actions and Controllers** , i.e. in your business logic you can create a ActionFilterAttribute and log those exceptions to ELMAH.

example:

```c#
public class UnhandledExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) {
        Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(new Elmah.Error(context.Exception));
    }
}
```

Then wireup by adding that filter.

```c#
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Filters.Add(new UnhandledExceptionFilter());
    }
}
```

With the above approach following errors will not be handled:

- Exceptions thrown from controller constructors.
- Exceptions thrown from message handlers.
- Exceptions thrown during routing.
- Exceptions thrown during response content serialization

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/16/capturing-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api-s-with-elmah.aspx & http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling

In order for ELMAH to log **WEB API errors at the global level** such that all 500 Server errors are caught then do this:

Install nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.Contrib.WebApi/

Add the below to WebApiConfig

```c#
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...
        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());
        ...
    }
}
```

And if you want to show custom error messages for the 500 Server errors you can implement the new ExceptionHandler in Web Api (Note that ExceptionLogger and ExceptionHandler are different.)

```c#
class OopsExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult
        {
            Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
            Content = "Oops! Sorry! Something went wrong." +
                      "Please contact support@contoso.com so we can try to fix it."
        };
    }

    private class TextPlainErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = 
                             new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            response.Content = new StringContent(Content);
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling

Comment: thanks mate, this was helpful.  I was still scratching my head for a bit 'til I figured out how to make it work in my situation (where the WebApi is also running in the context of an MVC site); the answer was simply to also install the Elmah.MVC package.  I expand on that slightly on my blog post here:  http://dbarrowstechblog.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/elmah-aspnet-webapi-tip.html

Comment: The first (simple) solution that directly calls  `Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log` works fine, but it doesn't send an email (if that's how you've got Elmah set up) - it just logs.  If you want your exception handled by Elmah in the manner you've specified in web.config, then I'd suggest replacing the .Log call with `Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);` which will trigger the normal Elmah handling.

Answer (score 16):

one option would be to setup a custom ExceptionFilterAttribute, override the OnException method, and signal Elmah from there. See the sample link below

[Elmah WebAPI Sample](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-and-elmah-integration)

Comment: The thing I struggled with (and still haven't found the time to address) is having forms authentication on my elmah access mixed with basic auth on my api

Answer (score 13):

Check the below URL it describe in details how to use elmah with Web API:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/16/capturing-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api-s-with-elmah.aspx

You can also use the NuGet Package below:

```
Install-Package Elmah.Contrib.WebApi
```

Usage:

> Simply register it during your application's start up, or on a controller-by-controller basis.
>
> ```c#
> protected void Application_Start()
> {
>     GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorApiAttribute());
>
>     ...
> }
> ```

(from [the Elmah.Contrib.WebApi GitHub repo](https://github.com/rdingwall/elmah-contrib-webapi))

Comment: This worked for me, should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 4):

For ASP.NET Web API use the  [Elmah.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC) nuget package, details of which are given below

*Taken from : [HOW TO SETUP ELMAH.MVC WITH ASP.NET MVC 4 ?](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-setup-elmah-mvc-with-asp-net-mvc-4/)*

**What is Elmah ?**

ELMAH is an open source project whose purpose is to log and report unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET web applications.

**Why to use Elmah ?**

ELMAH serves as an unobtrusive interceptor of unhandled ASP.NET exceptions, those usually manifesting with the ASP.NET [yellow screen of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_Screen_of_Death).

So now we know what and why to use Elmah, Lets quickly get started on how to use Elmah with your ASP.NET MVC project.

**Step 1:** Right click on your solution and select the "Manage Nuget Packages" option [image]

**Step 2:** In the Nuget Package manager search for "Elmah" and install the [Elmah.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC) nuget extension.
[image]
The Nuget Package manager will download and add the required dlls and modify the web.config's `<appSetting>` for Elmah to wo[image]rk.

**Step 3:** That's it !! Your Elmah is now ready to test. I have generated a 404 to test if my Elmah works, ELMAH can be accessed by this url : *http://yourapp.com/elmah*.
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps :)

**Further Reading :**

- [Elmah on code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC)
- [Elmah.MVC 2.0.2 on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC)
- [Elmah.MVC on GitHub](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc)

Comment: And are you generating that 404 from an `ApiController`? If not, and it's a standard MVC controller, you've missed the point of the question completely.

Comment: Have generated 404 from a normal controller, this is just an example, same would have been the case had i used the webapi controller and cause a 404.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Because I'm pretty sure that's not the case. Exception handling works differently in Web API.

Comment: @Doozer1979 said who ? You just need to register your `HttpFilters` here is how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059563/elmah-and-api-controller-in-mvc4-not-logging-errors/10067886#10067886

Comment: Well, why not make that part of your answer then, instead of leaving something up which doesn't work for the OP's question.

Comment: So does this solution work or not? I am wanting to implement elmah into my web api project. This is a very well answered post except it missed the point slightly.

Comment: @Zapnologica This answer + http://stackoverflow.com/a/13264550/1182982 will help you for sure :)