# Implementing Elmah in web api project

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, elmah.mvc

I am trying to implement ELMAH in a webapi project,since I am new to this elmah technique,I am not able to implement the entire thing.I even tried to follow the sample codes in web but still I am not getting.

can someone please help me to achieve a proper working solution with elmah.
I will be very thankful if a working solution is provided for demo purpose which will be really helpful for me to understand

Comment: There is already a question concerning this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116593/how-to-set-up-elmah-with-asp-net-web-api

Comment: Please check out the solution from [@ahmed-ahemd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388788/ahmed-ahmed) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21856256/3974799

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps to send error emails using Elmah

1. Install [Elmah Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah)
2. Update config file to use proper SMTP settings. Here is the example of config file settings

   ```
   < security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
   < errorMail subject="Production Error - {1}: {0}" smtpServer="server address" from="me@you.com" to="you@me.com" />
   ```
3. Create `ExceptionLogger` class. Here is the example of it

   ```
   public class ElmahExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
   {
     private const string HttpContextBaseKey = "MS_HttpContext";

     public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
     {
       // Retrieve the current HttpContext instance for this request.
       HttpContext httpContext = GetHttpContext(context.Request);

       // Wrap the exception in an HttpUnhandledException so that ELMAH can capture the original error page.
       Exception exceptionToRaise = new HttpUnhandledException(message: null, innerException: context.Exception);

       ErrorSignal signal;
       if (httpContext == null)
       {
          signal = ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext();
          // Send the exception to ELMAH (for logging, mailing, filtering, etc.).
          signal.Raise(exceptionToRaise);
       }
       else
       {
           signal = ErrorSignal.FromContext(httpContext);
           signal.Raise(exceptionToRaise);
       }
   }

   private static HttpContext GetHttpContext(HttpRequestMessage request)
   {
       HttpContextBase contextBase = GetHttpContextBase(request);

       if (contextBase == null)
       {
           return null;
       }

       return ToHttpContext(contextBase);
   }

   private static HttpContextBase GetHttpContextBase(HttpRequestMessage request)
   {
       if (request == null)
       {
           return null;
       }

       object value;

       if (!request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpContextBaseKey, out value))
       {
           return null;
       }

       return value as HttpContextBase;
   }

   private static HttpContext ToHttpContext(HttpContextBase contextBase){return contextBase.ApplicationInstance.Context; } }
   ```
4. Register `ElmahExceptionLogger` class with Web API in `startup.cs`

   ```
   config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Even though the answer by @Paresh works, you should use the [Elmah.Contrib.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.Contrib.WebApi/) package, since that includes everything needed to use ELMAH with Web API.

I've written a guide to [install ELMAH with Web API](http://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-web-api/). Basically you will install the `ELMAH` and `Elmah.Contrib.WebApi` packages and then configure it like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...
        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());
        ...
    }
}
```

Regarding the mail configuration, you can validate your web.config using the [ELMAH Configuration Validator](https://elmah.io/tools/configvalidator).